# How to get a Flex 4.5 checkbox to change string value (text)

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4.5, flexbuilder

What i am trying to do is very simple but it does not seem to work

I am trying to get a checkbox event handler to change the text value of a string.

```
protected function
transport_yes_catching_bus_to_venue_checkbox_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if (transport_yes_catching_bus_to_venue_checkbox.selected==true)
{
totals_transport_I_catch_bus_to_venue.text = "YES"
}
}
```

and this is my label before the change is applied

```
<s:Label id="totals_transport_I_catch_bus_to_venue"
includeIn="a13_summary_for_submission"
x="170" y="625" color="#3B70D1" text="-----"/>
```

The idea is for the label to be changed from "----" to "YES" if the checkbox has been clicked. Otherwise the label stays as it was.

When i run the application the label does not change regardless of the state of checkbox.

THANKS!!

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the event handler to verify that it is actually executing?  Are you using the debug version of the Flash Player to see if you get any runtime errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:Label id="totals_transport_I_catch_bus_to_venue" includeIn="a13_summary_for_submission"
x="170" y="625" color="#3B70D1" text="{cbInput.selected?'YES':'-----'}" />

<s:CheckBox id="cbInput" />
```

Comment: In theory this should work, but why wouldn't the approach used by the original poster work?